# facebook user location fetch via SpringSocial

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I have  a code to fetch user details
In location area
I have used this code in controller class

`model.addAttribute("location",facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getLocation());`

this error shows in jsp view in the location box.

location :org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Reference@97d487

birthday :not showing any thing
but showing gender: male
pls help..why??

Answer (score 0):

Location is an object. I think you want to show a value of **name** property:

```
facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getLocation().getName()
```

You may not have enough permissions to view birthday date. Are you sure that you already requested **user_birthday** access in login / signup form :

```
<form class="fb_signin" action="/signin/facebook" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="...,user_birthday,..." />
</form>
```

See all available permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions).